# ProxyPassMatch almost works

Tags: linux, apache, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy on a Linux server. I need all requests for the domain, http://new-website.com/, to a serve content from this subdirectory structure of my main site, http://website.com/new-website/.

I started out trying to use ProxyPass with this virtual hosts configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName new-website.com
    ServerAlias www.new-website.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
    ProxyPass "/" "http://website.com/new-website/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I realized after I set this up it would only work for the specific rule. So I attempted to update this using wildcards but then realized that ProxyPass does not accept wildcards. So I set up a new rule using ProxyPassMatch to use wildcards.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName coastalplainbbq.com
    ServerAlias www.coastalplainbbq.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://fitzgerald.asystyou.tech/coastal-plain-bbq/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

This works for this scenario:

```
http://new-website.com/
```

That displays the contents from the appropriate subdirectory on my main site:

```
http://website.com/new-website/
```

But when I try to drill down one more level the reverse proxy stops working and the main site URL with subdirectory is shown in the browser address bar. Example:

```
http://new-website.com/subdirectory-1/
```

This should keep the URL in the browser address bar just like I entered it above and serve up the contents of:

```
http://website.com/new-website/subdirectory-1/
```

But instead the URL in the browsers address bar switches and shows the URL for the main website. I updated the ProxyPassMatch rule one more time in an attempt to capture the scenarios properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName coastalplainbbq.com
    ServerAlias www.coastalplainbbq.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*?)(/.+?)?$ http://fitzgerald.asystyou.tech/coastal-plain-bbq/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

This does not work either. It gives me the same result as the original ProxyPassMatch rule. The primary domain displays and works right, but once I add a subdirectory the URL in the browser address bar switches back to the original URL.

I am still new to Linux/Apache and I have run out of ideas. I have a rule that does this identical thing configured with Windows/IIS and I have tried to use the same logic here but it doesn't work.

It seems like I am close to having this work, but I am stuck. Help please.